# Deleting a video using YouTube API v3 PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have the following code to delete a YouTube video using cURL. I'm getting a 401 response/authorization error. I've put in the API key in the url and do I put the access token in the bearer value in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` area?

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID_HERE&key=KEY_HERE";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/json','Authorization : Bearer '.$_SESSION['access_token']));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Are there any other mistakes I'm making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I had another question on the same topic (deleting videos) so I'll post that answer here now that I've figured it out in case someone finds this via Google. I never figured out the cURL method but the method using the google PHP library for v3 of their API is as follows:

```
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
...
//do your authoraisation stuff + getting access token etc
...
$youtube->videos->delete('<Your Video ID>');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you show how you did the authorization stuff + the token?

Comment: @J_Strauton sample code can be found here https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php